# Visio Api Connecting Shapes

Tags: c#, api, visio

I'm extending my application to export Diagrams to Visio, everything works perfect - I'm adding as much shapes I want and exactly at positions I need them.

PROBLEM: when trying to connect between two shapes - both of them change position - what am I doing wrong?

I have tried:

```
shapeFrom.AutoConnect(shapeTo, VisAutoConnectDir.visAutoConnectDirNone);
```

and also from the SDK:

```
ConnectWithDynamicGlueAndConnector
```

The same results: connection added- but the shapes are repositioned.

Answer (score 0):

Visio has a feature which allows auto-positioning of shapes.The problem is probably shape settings (automatic layout) - check if you have these configured for your shapes (Shape => Behavior, plow/layout options). It's hard to tell more without looking at your diagram. You can also try the specialized Visio forum, such as visguy.com

Comment: thanks - it was exactly an issue - the default setting - when creating a Master Shape - is to allow Visio to deside where to put the Shape ... took couple a days to figure it out...because on Drop Visio puts it where expected - but on connect - it is repositioning the shape according to own logic...

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who got into the same issue:

While creating a Master Shape it comes with predefined options, which allow Visio to move a shape into "better" position. It can completely frustrate you when you place two shapes and connect them with Dynamic Connector just to find both of them in a different place. To change this behavior some changes need to be made in Master Behavior, not sure if all of them are necessary but here are my settings that made the difference:

1) Select the group, go to Developer =>Behaviour

[image]

2) on the first Tab:

[image]

3) and on the last tab:

[image]

Summary: With this when you place a shape, it will stay at the same place even after connecting it with another shape.